# Type with string indexes of array

Tags: typescript

In some third-party code I found a strange type definition which I didn't see before.

```js
type SomeType = [from: number, to: number];
```

No idea how this is called in docs so I could not find anything about it. Can someone explain me please what does it mean?

PS. `const q: SomeType = [1, 2];` compiles just fine so I guess it's still a simple array of two numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is [Labeled tuple elements](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#labeled-tuple-elements)

Treat labels `from` and `to` just as a comments. They don't affect type itself in any way. It is just for readability.